# Polyglot function to sum all the numbers in an array in Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, array, polyglot

This, again, is a very simple code.

This is my 2nd polyglot question and this time I've tried to do something that I miss sometimes in Javascript.

PHP has the `array_sum()` function, but Javascript has no *direct* equivalent.

So, I decided to make one that works with both languages!

Here is the code:

```
function sum_array()
{
    if( $javascript = '\0' == "\0" )
    {
        $vars = new Object();
        $vars['args'] = arguments;
        $vars['l'] = arguments.length;
    }
    else
    {
        $vars = Array();
        $vars['args'] = func_get_args();
        $vars['l'] = func_num_args();
    }

    for( $vars['sum'] = $vars['i'] = 0; $vars['i'] < $vars['l']; $vars['i']++ )
    {
        $vars['m'] = $javascript ? $vars['args'][$vars['i']].length : count($vars['args'][$vars['i']]);

        for( $vars['j'] = 0; $vars['j'] < $vars['m']; $vars['j']++ )
        {
            $vars['sum'] += ( $vars['args'][$vars['i']][$vars['j']] / 1 ? $vars['args'][$vars['i']][$vars['j']] : 0 );
        }
    }

    return $vars['sum'];
}
```

Usability is really easy:

Simply pass multiple `array`s as arguments. In PHP, it is required to be an `array` with only numeric keys. This is due to the limitations of Javascript.

Example of usage:

```
sum_array([1,2,3,4,5],[15]); //should return 30 in Javascript and PHP 5.4+
```

To avoid 'poisoning' the `window` object, I only created 2 variables and use one of them as an `array` (The other is just to save if we are running in Javascript or PHP).

Was this a good decision?

What else can I improve on my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

You are trying to avoid poisoning the window object.. Now consider writing several functions like this. You just moved the poisoning from `window` to `$vars`. I would not do this because it reduces readability a lot.

`$vars['args'][$vars['i']]` should be in a helper variable to increase readability. (Regardless of whether you keep `$vars`)

I would have put this in a function called `get_array_length`:
`$javascript ? $vars['args'][$vars['i']].length : count($vars['args'][$vars['i']]);`

Then I would change the top to

```
if( $javascript = '\0' == "\0" )
{
    $vars = new Object();
    $vars['args'] = arguments;
}
else
{
    $vars = Array();
    $vars['args'] = func_get_args();
}
$vars['l'] = get_array_length($vars['args'])
```

Still, all in all because you need to maintain compatibility this is okay as an *art* excercise but this is by no means (because of  it's nature) production or high quality code.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the delay in commenting. I was interrupted a few times. I like your idea of using a helper function. I aprove that! About the variable, I agree that it isn't the cleanest way. And yes, my intention isn't to use it in production but simply as an exercise to practice a little on this 'art'. This is nowhere close to an overkill multi-language polyglot. I really appreciate your help. But the only thing I don't know is how to make local variables in Javascript without using the keyword `var` (which causes syntax errors in PHP). But maybe it is impossible. Once again, thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell it is impossible. I wouldnt worry about it.

Comment: As far as I can tell too, it is really impossible. Maybe some `eval()` voodoo would work?